# Gradle task code conflicts with gradle's dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, integration-testing

My integration tests need to configure a database, but the libraries that I use to do this need newer versions of libraries that Gradle uses (similar to [this issue](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/log4j-over-slf4j-version-upgrade)). For my production code, this isn't a problem because I can declare the dependency on the newer version. However, my understanding is that it makes the most sense to put code that initializes and destroys the general test infrastructure in buildSrc so that it can be used in tasks. For this code, that doesn't work because it gets Gradle's versions of the dependencies (SLF4J in this case).

What is the best workaround for this? Is there a way to create a Gradle task that can use its own version of the libraries, or is there a good way to do this kind of initialization outside of the Gradle tasks?

Comment: Some time ago I also had similar issue (with guava exactly) and I finished with copying methods I need to my src files :/

Comment: @Opal Thanks, it's good to know that someone else has seen something similar. Unfortunately, in my case copying the methods won't work because the database library is looking for SLF4J functionality that was added in a later version.

Comment: Yeah, thus it wasn't an answer but just a comment, a poor comment :/